# BeautifulSoup4 Get_Text() Removing Line Breaks?

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm having a bit of an issue with get_text() compared to what I would normally be able to do with .Net I think it's removing line breaks which makes it impossible for me to parse the data.

I'm reading a class from a site in this kind of format:

```
4.1 £22 4 £27 3.9 £29 3.8 £106 3.75 £24 3.7 £24
```

It'll follow the same format: decimal price decimal price decimal price etc...

I've done this in .Net and element.innertext has returned a string with a line break in between.

I was able to do something like:

```
Dim spltexample As String() = element.innertext.Split(New String() {Environment.NewLine},
                                           StringSplitOptions.None)
```

It would put a decimal and price into each result. So it was seeing:

```
4.1 £22\n 4 £27\n 3.9 £29\n 3.8 £106\n 3.75 £24\n 3.7 £24
```

My problem is BS4 seems to be getting it in a slightly different format - and I'm really hoping this is something I can change.

```
4.1 £224 £273.9 £29 3.8 £1063.75 £243.7 £24
```

**It's squashing the decimal into the preceding price by removing the new line.**

The data can be pretty awkward. The numbers won't be static and I need to know how many combinations of decimal and price there is. The .Net would give me a list like:

```
4.1 £22
4 £27
3.9 £29
3.8 £106
3.75 £24
3.7 £24
```

Current code:

```
for result in soup.find_all("span", {"class" : "classname"}):
            List_Of_Results.append(result .get_text())
```

Example output:

```
  4.1 £224 £273.9 £29 3.8 £1063.75 £243.7 £24
```

This has left me pretty dead in the water. Is there anything else I can use to get the data and leave the line breaks intact so I can work with them?

Comment: try get_text(separator=u"\n")

Comment: Perfect. Thanks so much for that I'll have to dig more into the documentation and get a better understanding of get_text going forwards.

Comment: I believe you can get text (including newlines) using the `.string` (or `.strings` it's hard to tell without your specific url) attribute instead of the `.get_text()` method.